# How to retrieve records from data extension of different business unit using AMPScript REST API call and also how to insert record

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript

I am using this call in AMPScript
To retrieve:
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/[Data extension key]?$filter= Name%20eq%20'Test'

To insert:
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:[Data extension key]/rowset

```
Body:
  [{ 
   "keys":{
          "FA_Response_ID": "1234567"
          },
    "values":{
    "Email":"abc@gmail.com"
     "Subscriber_Key":"abc@gmail.com",
      "TS_Status_Message":"NEW_MSG" 
          }
     }]
```

both calls are working in POSTMAN but not in AMPScript
Getting error while insert call
"JSON Deserialization Exception: Location Unknown"

Comment: You could add your non working AMPScript (without customer values etc). This would help us to figure out what is wrong in your ampscript

Comment: @Vasudha You should make sure your using the same account which you asked the question under to make edits to it. Otherwise 2+ people need to approve your edits. See [Merging Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to include your access token with AMPscript's `HTTPGet` when requesting the GET route to retrieve DE rows (i.e., you'll need to momentarily step into SSJS), but here's one approach...

```
External Key: xyz789
┌───────────────┬──────┐
│ EmailAddress  │ User │
├───────────────┼──────┤
│ foo@bar.baz   │ foo  │
├───────────────┼──────┤
│ qux@quux.quuz │ qux  │
└───────────────┴──────┘
```

...

```
%%[
set @creds =
'{
  "clientId": "abc123",
  "clientSecret": "456def"
}'
set @reqTokenStatus = HTTPPost(
  'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken',
  'application/json',
  @creds,
  @reqTokenResponse
)
set @accessToken = RegExMatch(
  @reqTokenResponse,
  '"accessToken"\s*?:\s*?"(.+?)"',
  1,
  'None'
)



if (@reqTokenStatus == 200) and (Length(@accessToken) > 0) then
  set @dataExtKey = 'xyz789'
  set @payload =
'[
  {
    "keys": {
      "EmailAddress": "foo@bar.baz"
    },
    "values": {
      "User": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    "keys": {
      "EmailAddress": "qux@quux.quuz"
    },
    "values": {
      "User": "qux"
    }
  }
]'

  set @reqInsertRowsStatus = HTTPPost(
    Concat('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:', @dataExtKey, '/rowset'),
    'application/json',
    @payload,
    @reqInsertRowsResponse,
    'Authorization', Concat('Bearer ', @accessToken)
  )

  if (@reqInsertRowsStatus == 200) then
    Output(Concat('Rows inserted:<br>', @reqInsertRowsResponse, '<br><br>'))

    set @retrieveRowsFilter = Concat('$filter=', URLEncode("User eq 'Foo'", 0, 1))
    set @retrieveRowsRoute = Concat('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/', @dataExtKey, '/rowset/?', @retrieveRowsFilter)
    set @reqRetriveRowsResponse = ''
]%%
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load('Core', '1');
var accessToken = Variable.GetValue('@accessToken');
var retrieveRowsRoute = Variable.GetValue('@retrieveRowsRoute');
var headerNames = ['Authorization'];
var headerValues = [('Bearer ' + accessToken)];
var reqRetriveRowsResponse = HTTP.Get(retrieveRowsRoute, headerNames, headerValues);
Variable.SetValue('@reqRetriveRowsResponse', reqRetriveRowsResponse.Content);
</script>
%%[
    Output(Concat('Rows retrieved:<br>', @reqRetriveRowsResponse))
  endif

/* unable to complete request */

endif
]%%
```